# best web design approach

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

I'm more of a asp.net web app dev, I came across my first side project and I stumbled on what is the best way to style a web page.

Here's my problem: I need to style a master page so any content that comes in the content place holder would fit.

I tried:

1. divs that have position of where to go, but it didn't work for dynamic content (like a repeater) as it overflows beyond the div because I specified position styles for the container div.
2. tables that have rows and cells that moves the content to the desired position but when there is a repeater in the big cell (which is the main page content) it splits the page and messes it up.

Any thoughts of how to best start to style the master page so it will hold dynamic content in it.

Comment: Have you considered using a grid system such as 960gs or the-golden-grid?

Comment: Developer should develop, designer should design :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`divs` are for positioning, `tables` for tabular data. If your `divs` are not positioned properly when the page is rendered ; something on your `css` is not playing nice. The fact that you have a Master Page or not will not affect the way your HTML elements are rendered.

Comment: I thought I was right the first time, but when the page renders a high volumn data it overflows, so I thought may be my approach was wrong so I switched to the table. I'll play around with css and see how things are going.

Comment: you were right, css wasn't playing nice, I found the culprit and now the divs are expanding like a beauty! thanks for all. Oh the problem was that I was specifying positioning css on divs that makes them stick to certain position and size, I removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your first project, it is expected. I would say your first approach is fine with the div layout. I am assuming that you don't have the Firebug Installed. Get it [HERE](http://getfirebug.com/) and see properly which element is being rendered how and what attribute it takes. It is a slow process and you will get used to it. I am assuming that you are a noob.

Comment: it my first personal project yes and I think I'm a noob when it comes to webpage design, but I'm using dev tools for ie and chrome, I know about firebug but dev tools are doing the job for me for the moment.